# How to replace multiple values in 1 column in mysql SELECT query using REPLACE()?

Tags: mysql, sql, replace

I have a table with Boolean values (0 and 1 only) that needs to be CSV-ed to  a client. I know I can do 1 replace like this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(email, '%40', '@'),
       REPLACE(name,'%20', ' '),
       REPLACE(icon_clicked, 1, 'Yes') 
FROM myTable 
WHERE id > 1000;
```

This will convert all the values of 1 to 'Yes', but how to do this in a single query for both 1 => Yes and 0 => No    so Boolean result is stored in a single column? I tried to do this:

```
SELECT REPLACE(email, '%40', '@'),
       REPLACE(name,'%20', ' '),
       REPLACE(icon_clicked, 1, 'Yes'),
       REPLACE(icon_clicked, 0, 'No')
FROM myTable
WHERE id > 1000;
```

But this query created an additional column for the 'No' string replace (so final result had 4 columns, email, name, icon_clicked->yes, icon_clicked->no)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One way is to nest `REPLACE`:

```
SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(icon_clicked, 0, 'No'), 1, 'Yes')), ...
FROM myTable
...
```

or use `CASE WHEN` (this will work for most RDBMS comparing to `IF` function which is MySQL related):

```
SELECT CASE WHEN icon_clicked THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END, ...
FROM myTable
...
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b42d9/11/0)**</kbd>

**EDIT:**

There is also one nice way utilizing [`ELT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/string-functions.html#function_elt):

```
SELECT icon_clicked,
       ELT(FIELD(icon_clicked,0,1),'No','Yes'),
       ELT(icon_clicked + 1, 'No', 'Yes')
FROM mytable
```

<kbd>**[`SqlFiddleDemo2`](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b42d9/22/0)**</kbd>

Answer (score 4):

No need to use nested `Replace` or `Case` statement. Try using [**IF**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if), which is way simpler

```
SELECT 
   icon_clicked,
   IF(icon_clicked,'Yes','No')
FROM myTable
```

- [**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5b42d9/15)